# Uniform convergence on compact subset and integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $(a,b)$ be a open interval and $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $(a,b)$. Given $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $0$-function on  any compact subset of $(a,b)$. I want to show that:
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^a_b f_n=0$$
I know that by uniform convergence I can switch the integration and limit, so the intergration is 0 for any compact subset of $(a,b)$. But I can't pass the conclusion through the whole $(a,b)$. This seems to be intuitive but I cannot write down a rigirous proof of it. Any help is apperetiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $a=0,b=1,f_n(x)=n-n^{2}x$ for $0<x<\frac 1 n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\geq \frac 1 n$. Can you check that this serves as a counterexample?

Comment: Note that for any closed interval $[c,d]\subset (0,1)$ we have $f_n(x)=0 \forall x \in [c,d]$ whenever $\frac 1 n <c$.

Comment: You are right, I thought it was assumed uniformly convergent to zero on $(a,b)$